# Strange results from stretchblt depending on dimensions

Tags: c++, image, winapi

So I was playing around with stretchblt and, I noticed a strange correlation when I take a partial capture of my screen. As long as the dimensions of the capture match a commonly used resolution (say a RECT of { 0, 0, 224, 144}) I get something like this: 
[244x144 Res](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZa4p.jpg)

However if I change the dimensions by one pixel (say a RECT of { 0, 0, 225, 144}) I get something like this: [255x144](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ng6Oz.jpg)

Here's a code sample if that's even necessary.  I could really use some insight into why this is happening.  Thanks for any help!

```
    void CaptureScreen(RECT imageDim, std::vector<uint8_t>& vecData)
{
    BYTE* pScreenData = nullptr;
    LONG mapWidth = imageDim.right - imageDim.left;
    LONG mapHeight = imageDim.bottom - imageDim.top;

    HDC desktopDC = GetDC(NULL);
    HDC captureDC = CreateCompatibleDC(desktopDC);

    BITMAPINFO bmpInfo;
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(bmpInfo.bmiHeader);
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 24;
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth = mapWidth;
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight = mapHeight;
    bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = mapWidth*mapHeight * 3;

    HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateDIBSection(captureDC, &bmpInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**)(&pScreenData), NULL, NULL);

    SelectObject(captureDC, hBitmap);

    StretchBlt(captureDC,   // Destination device context
        0,                                  // x-coordinate of destination rect
        mapHeight,                                  // y-coordinate of destination rect
        mapWidth,                           // width of destination rect
        -mapHeight,                         // height of destination rect
        desktopDC,                  // Desktop device context
        imageDim.left,                      // x-coordinate of source rectangle
        imageDim.top,                       // y-coordinate of source rectangle
        mapWidth,                           // width of source rect
        mapHeight,                          // height of source rect
        SRCCOPY);

    DeleteObject(hBitmap);

    SaveImage(pScreenData, imageDim);
}
```

Comment: Bitmaps are always a multiple of 4 bytes wide.  If necessary there's padding and you need to account for it.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I'll have to do a bit of reading up on bitmaps.  I'm assuming there's some reasoning behind it.

Comment: `BITMAP.bmWidthBytes` is the field in question. Other APIs call this a "stride", and there might be other names as well. Use `GetObject()`.